# Use Ethereum TestRPC with Web3 IPC Provider

Tags: web3js, testrpc, ipc

Can I use TestRPC only with http or can I set it up with ipc as well?
If yes - how?

Answer (score 1):

From the help page of testrpc I can not see that there is an option for IPC. Only host and port for RPC can be specified.

-> https://github.com/ethereumjs/testrpc